# Multithread http file uploads

Tags: html, file-upload, multifile-uploader

Is it possible to multithread file uploads using http post requests (not ftp)?  Are there any flash or java uploaders that take advantage of multithreaded uploads?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, and I'm sure there are several Flash and Java applets that supports it. It's just a matter of creating separate connections. Here's one of the results I found [using Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=flash+multiple+upload):

http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 MultiFile uploads and this is example:

http://safron.su/playground/html5uploader/

P.S. This example is designed to load the picture.

Comment: While I'd much prefer a HTML5 solution, I need the ability to upload directories (which only the Java seems to accomodate).